# Synchronize accounts down from Azure AD to on-premises?

Tags: azure

Just installed an on-premises AD forest to join with our Azure AD. I setup AD connect for synchronization. I want to sync down the accounts from Azure AD into my new on-premises AD forest (which is brand new and empty). I only see instructions for pushing on-premises account up, but nothing about pulling them down. Any ideas what I'm missing?

Comment: Someone can correct me, but Azure AD was one-way only last time I checked. As for like password it only send the hash, not the full info up, it was why it's was one way only.

Comment: you drank the cool aide, now you have to pony up $$$$

Comment: @yagmoth555 You can sync passwords both directions, so you can reset the PW using Azure AD and then sync back down to on prem, that works already, but not full account sync,

Answer (score 1):

you didn't miss anything, Azure AD Connect only syncs user accounts from your on premises AD to your Azure AD.
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-aadconnect/

Pascal

Comment: There was a preview feature available for a while that did go the other way but it was withdrawn.  I suspect it will be back at some point.

Answer (score 0):

However you build around it with a topology like this if you need to provision user in azure for hybrid env

Azure AD -> Azure AD Domain Services -> forest trust -> On prem ADDS -> Azure AD connect -> Azure AD

That would solve your problem if I understand you correct

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/reference-architectures/identity/adds-forest
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-domain-services/synchronization